# Can range-v3 iota_view iterator be random access for 64 bit initial value?

Tags: c++, std-ranges, range-v3

It appears that the range-v3 iota_view iterator is not random access when you use a 64 bit type for the initial value. It works ok for gcc iota_view. It works for range-v3 with a 32 bit initial value. Here is a simple example in compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/dEG7aKnoc. It uses gcc 13 and trunk for range-v3. I also list the code below.

Is there a way to make it be random access?

```
#if 1
// range v3
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
namespace rng = ::ranges;

#else
#include <ranges>
namespace rng = std::ranges;
#endif

int main()
{

    // works
    // int base = 100;

    // does not work
    //std::size_t base = 100;
    //long base = 100;
    ssize_t base = 100;

    static_assert(std::random_access_iterator<decltype(rng::begin(rng::views::iota(base)))>);
}
```

Comment: I need a view because it is too big to materialize in memory.

Answer (score 1):

A local C++ expert had the answer. Use `rng::random_access_iterator` instead of `std::random_access_iterator`.

> I believe the issue here is that the difference type for this range
> std::ranges::__detail::__max_diff_type is not a signed integral type.
> I think this will go away if you use rng::random_access_iterator.
> (i.e. range-v3 uses a weird 128-bit difference_type for iota with
> 64-bit integers, and this is not recognized as a valid difference type
> by the standard library) (libstdc++ uses a 64-bit difference type and
> just doesn’t worry about the potential for overflow/underflow)